# cannot make the except conditions run as expected

Tags: python-3.x

in this simple code I expect the result to be :

wrong range or wrong color

but no matter what it doesn't work as expected can you help out.

```
pen = 'yellow'
lan = 5
try :
    if pen == 'yellow' and lan <= 40 and lan >=10 :
        print ('color yellow within range')
except :
    print('wrong range or wrong color ')
```

EDIT #1
I get that this proplem can be solved in this situation using if , else but for a sligtly more complicated code such as this

```
pen = input('color: ')
lan = input( 'number: ')
lan = int(lan)
try :
    if pen == 'yellow' and lan <= 40 and lan >=10 :
        print ('color yellow within range')
    elif pen == 'green' and lan <= 60 and lan >= 30 :
        print ('color green within range')
except :
    print('wrong range or wrong color ')
```

how can the try and except be used in this context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
pen = 'yellow'
lan = 5
if pen == 'yellow' and lan <= 40 and lan >=10 :
    print ('color yellow within range')
else:
    print('wrong range or wrong color ')
```

Comment: could you have a look on the second code and tell me what you think

Comment: @AhmedMedhat The exception might come from the convertion of "lan" to int, if you put the convertion of the variable into the try block, if python wouldn't be able to convert it into an integer, for example if lan = "lol", this will go to the except block.
Saying that, you can check if you can convert a string into an integer in python, and not using try/except at all.

Comment: okay now I get it. thanks alot @netanel that was very helpful

Comment: @AhmedMedhat Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand try-except. `except` only executes in response ta a `raise`. What you want here is a simple `else`, i think.

```py
pen = 'yellow'
lan = 5
if pen == 'yellow' and lan <= 40 and lan >=10 :
    print ('color yellow within range')
else :
    print('wrong range or wrong color ')
```

Comment: okay this could actually work if it's a simple code like the one I posted but what about this code. do you think the if and else would still work in this situation or should it be try and except :    
pen = 'yellow'
lan = 5
try :
    if pen == 'yellow' and lan <= 40 and lan >=10 :
        print ('color yellow within range')
    elif pen == 'green' and lan <= 60 and lan >= 30 :
        print ('color green within range')
except :
    print('wrong range or wrong color ')

Comment: Yes it would still work. if-elif-elif-elif-else. `except` is out of place here. I think you still misunderstand the meaning of `except`.